# Setting a guest to be group owner using AzureADDirectorySetting AllowGuestsToBeGroupOwner

Tags: powershell, azure-active-directory, azure-powershell, microsoft-teams

I've been trying to allow a Guest to be an Owner in a Microsoft Teams using [New-AzureADObjectSetting](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/active-directory-accessmanagement-groups-settings-cmdlets#update-settings-for-a-specific-group) and struggling:

```ps
$Template = Get-AzureADDirectorySettingTemplate -Id 08d542b9-071f-4e16-94b0-74abb372e3d9
$Setting = $Template.CreateDirectorySetting()
$Setting["AllowGuestsToBeGroupOwner"]=$True
New-AzureADObjectSetting -TargetType Groups -TargetObjectId mygroupId -DirectorySetting $Setting
```

This doesn't seem to stick. I've tried allowing the user to invite Guests as well as setting them in Azure AD as limited administrator - but no luck...

It may not be possible, but the setting is available and cant be misread. 
Suggestions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This can now be done with the help of this article https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-365/solutions/manage-creation-of-groups?view=o365-worldwide and a small change to included script.

Instead of changing property `EnableGroupCreation` and `GroupCreationAllowedGroupId` you'll change property `AllowGuestsToBeGroupOwner = $True` and it should work.